# SQL take just the numeric values from a varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Say i have a few fields like the following:

```
abd738927
jaksm234234
hfk342
ndma0834
jon99322
```

Type: varchar.

How do I take just the numeric values from this to display:

```
738927
234234
342
0834
99322
```

Have tried substring however the data varies in length, and cast didnt work either due to being unable to convert, any ideas?

Comment: Yep, patindex, assuming all numerics are grouped together, as in your example, else you might need a function.

Comment: Do you have to do this in SQL or is post-query manipulation allowed?  If so then I would use a regex to extract the number for display; I did a cursory search and did not come across anything that show that you can use a regular expression between SELECT and FROM.

Comment: @SelectDistinct - What is missing in my answer ? Did you test the accepted post with below code `DECLARE @a VARCHAR(1212) = 'eded123wsws'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@a, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @a), LEN(@a))`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here's the example with PATINDEX:

```
select SUBSTRING(fieldName, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', fieldName), LEN(fieldName))
```

This assumes (1) the field WILL have a numeric, (2) the numerics are all grouped together, and (3) the numerics don't have any subsequent characters after them.

Comment: And,  what if the field has no numbers?

Comment: @user990016 then add a `where` clause to filter those records out, or a `case` statement to return a default value for those records. So: `WHERE fieldName LIKE '%[0-9]%'` and `CASE WHEN fieldName NOT LIKE '%[0-9]%' THEN 'DEFAULT_VALUE' ELSE SUBSTRING(fieldName, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', fieldName), LEN(fieldName)) END`

Comment: What if the string starts with numbers and then characters and then again numbers?
For example: '123abc$%10xyz9'.
How can I get '123109' as the result with a select statement?

Answer (score 6):

Extract only numbers (without using while loop) and check each and every character to see if it is a number and extract it

```
   Declare @s varchar(100),@result varchar(100)
    set @s='as4khd0939sdf78' 
    set @result=''

    select
        @result=@result+
                case when number like '[0-9]' then number else '' end from 
        (
             select substring(@s,number,1) as number from 
            (
                select number from master..spt_values 
                where type='p' and number between 1 and len(@s)
            ) as t
        ) as t 
    select @result as only_numbers
```

Answer (score 4):

```
DECLARE @NonNumeric varchar(1000) = 'RGI000Testing1000'
DECLARE @Index int  
SET @Index = 0  
while 1=1  
begin  
    set @Index = patindex('%[^0-9]%',@NonNumeric)  
    if @Index <> 0  
    begin  
        SET @NonNumeric = replace(@NonNumeric,substring(@NonNumeric,@Index, 1), '')  
    end  
    else    
        break;   
end     
select @NonNumeric -- 0001000
```

Answer (score 4):

Well if you don't want to create a function, you can just something like this:

```
cast(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(
replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(
replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(YOUR_COLUMN
,'A',''),'B',''),'C',''),'D',''),'E',''),'F',''),'G',''),'H',''),'I',''),'J','')
,'K',''),'L',''),'M',''),'N',''),'O',''),'P',''),'Q',''),'R',''),'S',''),'T','')
,'U',''),'V',''),'W',''),'X',''),'Y',''),'Z',''),'$',''),',',''),' ','') as float)
```

Comment: This solution will haunt my dreams forever.

Comment: disturbing indeed

Comment: Ah, the heady days of LISP.

Comment: How can I unsee this?

Comment: It is beautiful yet ugly at the same time .
But seriously, don't use it for real production code for both performance and for readability reasons.

Comment: "I have no respect for those who have no respect for logic." - Arnold Schwarzenegger

Answer (score 2):

```
select substring(
                'jaksm234234',
                patindex('%[0-9]%','jaksm234234'),
                LEN('jaksm234234')-patindex('%[0-9]%','jaksm234234')+2
                )
```

Comment: I'm looking at your example and it gives a conversion to int error if the column does not contain any numbers.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

[input table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYEHe.png)

if you have  data like above in the image, then use the below query

```
select field_3 from table where PATINDEX('%[ ~`!@#$%^&*_()=+\|{};",<>/?a-z]%', field_3)=0
```

Results will be look like this

[Result table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfFSP.png)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're wanting VBA's `Val()` function.  Easy enough to accomplish with `IsNumeric()`

```
create function Val 
(
    @text nvarchar(40)
) 
returns float
as begin
    -- emulate vba's val() function
    declare @result float 
    declare @tmp varchar(40)

    set @tmp = @text
    while isnumeric(@tmp) = 0 and len(@tmp)>0 begin
        set @tmp=left(@tmp,len(@tmp)-1)
    end
    set @result = cast(@tmp as float)

    return @result
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Extract only numbers from a string. Returns a string with all the numbers inside. Example: this1is2one345long6789number will return 123456789

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetOnlyNumbers] (@Temp VARCHAR(1000))
```

`RETURNS VARCHAR (1000) AS BEGIN`

```
    DECLARE @KeepValues AS VARCHAR(50)
    SET @KeepValues = '%[^0-9]%'
    WHILE PATINDEX(@KeepValues, @Temp) > 0
        SET @Temp = STUFF(@Temp, PATINDEX(@KeepValues, @Temp), 1, '')

    RETURN @Temp
END
```

Answer (score 0):

A right with patindex for the reverse string works also for those

```
SELECT [Column], 
  CAST(RIGHT([Column], PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', REVERSE([Column])+' ')) AS INT) as [Num]
FROM (VALUES 
('abd738927'),
('jaksm234234'),
('hfk342'),
('ndma0834'),
('jon99322'),
) val([Column])
```

| Column | Num |
| --- | --- |
| abd738927 | 738927 |
| jaksm234234 | 234234 |
| hfk342 | 342 |
| ndma0834 | 834 |
| jon99322 | 99322 |