# i need to extract just the street/house number from varchar2 datatype

Tags: sql, oracle

We have a varchar2 column called House_Number, which has all different kind of data entries as shown below.
And all I need is the numbers from left to the first occurrence of a non-numeric like space, special characters and ascii characters.

Below are some sample house_numbers:

```
217 3RDFL, 2173RDFL, 500D, 527 # 2ND, 527# 2ND, 5422NDFL, 5422, 30# D2,
1250 2ND, 12502ND, 217 3RDFL, 2173RDFL, 5241R, 3 2R, 32R, 5092R, 24 # 2R,
24# 2R, 129 B-16, 129# B17, 129B-16, 16 # 2B, 4229B, 539# APT 3, 563 # A5,
2162A, 934-A, 109-A, 511-A, 339-REA, 339REAR
```

And for the above house_numbers, the expected corresponding outputs is as follows:

```
217, 217, 500, 527, 527, 542, 542, 30,1250,1250, 217, 217, 5241, 
3, 32, 5092, 24, 24, 129, 129, 129, 16, 4229, 539, 563, 2162, 
934, 109, 511, 339, 339
```

I tried using regexp_substr, but i could not get a logic which will work for all the different data inputs as shown above.

Would really appreciate if someone can help.

Comment: Post (add to your question using [Edit]) your best attempt so far.

Comment: I'd also suggest trying `patindex`. It's a pretty neat function that also uses RegEx. Edit: This is assuming SQL Server.

Comment: Is it always the first 3 numbers?

Comment: Partial duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11333078/sql-take-just-the-numeric-values-from-a-varchar (note the first answer with patindex, not the terrifying answer with all those replace()s)

Comment: sorry.....i did not mention in the question....

Comment: this is oracle 12c and it is not the first 3 numbers....

Comment: we want the numbers starting from left until the first occurrence of a non-numeric which is white space, null, special characters and ascii characters

Comment: Address parsing is a hard problem.  The USPS maintains a maintains a master list of all mailing addresses in the US and guards that data better than equifax.  You might want to consider using a CASS service such as https://smartystreets.com/ instead of implementing an incomplete process.

Comment: It is not "until the first occurrence of a non-numeric" - in your sample data, you have 2173RDFL and you extract 217, not 2173. So it is not as simple as "until the first occurrence of a non-numeric." Since you have this exception you must state ALL the exceptions to that rule, or you will get a solution just as flawed as your requirement.

Comment: Regular expresions me thinks @Philip

Comment: To explain further: If the input is `3739THFL` How do you know if you must extract 373, and `9THFL` means ninth floor? How do you know the number isn't 37, leaving `39THFL` to mean the 39th floor? SQL, software, computers in general can't answer such questions; they must be answered by you IN THE REQUIREMENT.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the response.....yes the challenge is when 3739THFL, how do we know if the correct number is 37 or 373 assuming this is either 9TH of 39TH floor.

Answer (score 2):

Using regexp_substr():

```
regexp_substr(house_number, '^[0-9]*')
```

That matches any number (`[0-9]`) occuring at the beginning of the word (`^`) repeated any number of times (`*`)

Comment: i dont have the perfect solution but below got me the closest for now....

Comment: select house_number,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(house_number,'1/2',''),'-',''), '+', ''), '.', ''), '#', ''), '?', ''),'^\d+') AS "House_Number"
from <table_name>
order by 1;

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution that I just built you can adjust/tweak:
**SQL:**

```
 DECLARE @HOUSE_NUMBER_DATA TABLE
    (
        HOUSE_NUMBER VARCHAR(25)
    )

INSERT INTO @HOUSE_NUMBER_DATA
SELECT '217 3RDFL '  UNION ALL
SELECT '2173RDFL  '  UNION ALL
SELECT '500D      '  UNION ALL
SELECT '527 # 2ND '  UNION ALL
SELECT '527# 2ND  '  UNION ALL
SELECT '5422NDFL  '  UNION ALL
SELECT '30# D2    '  UNION ALL
SELECT '1250 2ND  '  UNION ALL
SELECT '12502ND   '  UNION ALL
SELECT '217 3RDFL '  UNION ALL
SELECT '2173RDFL  '  UNION ALL
SELECT '5241R     '  UNION ALL
SELECT '3 2R      '  UNION ALL
SELECT '32R       '  UNION ALL
SELECT '5092R     '  UNION ALL
SELECT '24 # 2R   '  UNION ALL
SELECT '24# 2R    '  UNION ALL
SELECT '129 B-16  '  UNION ALL
SELECT '129# B17  '  UNION ALL
SELECT '129B-16   '  UNION ALL
SELECT '16 # 2B   '  UNION ALL
SELECT '4229B     '  UNION ALL
SELECT '539# APT 3'  UNION ALL
SELECT '563 # A5  '  UNION ALL
SELECT '2162A     '  UNION ALL
SELECT '934-A     '  UNION ALL
SELECT '109-A     '  UNION ALL
SELECT '511-A     '  UNION ALL
SELECT '339-REA   '  UNION ALL
SELECT '339REAR   '  

SELECT * FROM @HOUSE_NUMBER_DATA

SELECT SUBSTRING(HOUSE_NUMBER,0, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', HOUSE_NUMBER)) ONLY_FIRST_NUMBERS_NO_SPACES
    ,CASE --It will tough to account for 22nd floor vs 2nd floor with no spaces
        WHEN SUBSTRING(HOUSE_NUMBER, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',HOUSE_NUMBER),2) = 'RD' THEN SUBSTRING(HOUSE_NUMBER,0, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', HOUSE_NUMBER) -1)
        WHEN SUBSTRING(HOUSE_NUMBER, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',HOUSE_NUMBER),2) = 'R' THEN SUBSTRING(HOUSE_NUMBER,0, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', HOUSE_NUMBER) -1)
        WHEN SUBSTRING(HOUSE_NUMBER, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',HOUSE_NUMBER),2) = 'ND' THEN SUBSTRING(HOUSE_NUMBER,0, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', HOUSE_NUMBER) -1)
        ELSE SUBSTRING(HOUSE_NUMBER,0, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', HOUSE_NUMBER))
    END TRYING_TO_IGNORE_RD
    ,HOUSE_NUMBER
FROM @HOUSE_NUMBER_DATA
```

Not sure how to convert that to ORACLE though. (took out previous ORACLE section as the code doesn't seem to be correct, don't work with ORACLE)

Comment: Thanks for the sample code and the test table you created etc. But this is for Oracle 12C and i believe we need to replace SUBSTRING with substr and replace PATINDEX with regexp_like.

Comment: I didn't see the Oracle tag on there, only the SQL. Sorry about that.
Added a converted section under it from converter, so may or may not work.

Comment: @Philip can you confirm the Oracle section is correct snytex, it should get you the same result as the SQL part which I confirmed worked as you needed. Let me know when you can...

Comment: ....sorry i did not mention that this is for Oracle ...but only later added as a comment.... Thanks for the providing the Oracle syntax....below are some of the sample data...527 # 2ND
527# 2ND
5422NDFL
1250 2ND
1250 2ND
12502ND
12502ND
16682NDFL
4226 2NDFL
42262NDFL
...when i run your oracle script for the above sample data...i am getting NULL value as result....instead of capturing the numbers.....